# How do I Get a WPF DataGrid to Save Changes Back to the DataBase?

Tags: sql, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

How do I get a WPF DataGrid to save changes back to the database?

I've data-bound my DataGrid control to a DataTable object, and populated that table with a very simple SELECT query that retrieves some basic information. The data shows up just fine in the control.

But when I use the control to edit the data, the changes are not pushed back to the DB.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Performing Updates

When the user edits the Customers data within the DataGrid, the bound in-memory DataTable is updated accordingly. However, these updates are not automatically written back to the database. It is up to the developer to decide when changes to the DataTable are written back to the database depending on the requirements of the application. For example, in some cases, you might wish to submit a batch of changes via a "Submit" button, or you may wish to have the database updated as the user commits each row edit. In order to support these, the rows that the DataTable contains have a RowState property which indicates whether they contain changes which should be synchronized with the database. The synchronization process is easily achieved via the TableAdapter's Update method.
url:
[WPF DataGrid examples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx)

The following example shows how the RowChanged and RowDeleted events can be handled so that changes in the DataTable state are written to the database each time the user changes a row:

```
public CustomerDataProvider()
{
    NorthwindDataSet dataset = new NorthwindDataSet();

    adapter = new CustomersTableAdapter();
    adapter.Fill(dataset.Customers);

    dataset.Customers.CustomersRowChanged +=
        new NorthwindDataSet.CustomersRowChangeEventHandler(CustomersRowModified);
    dataset.Customers.CustomersRowDeleted +=
        new NorthwindDataSet.CustomersRowChangeEventHandler(CustomersRowModified);
}

void CustomersRowModified(object sender, NorthwindDataSet.CustomersRowChangeEvent e)
{
    adapter.Update(dataset.Customers);
}
```