# How to bind a grid to a viewmodel based on EF the proper way?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, mvvm

I inherited a project where the data model is created based on the database using EF 6. I'm creating a viewmodel as follows, where *Data* is the type that is autogenerated for my database context (i.e. it contains the fields corresponding to the tables in the DB).

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private Data _data = new Data();

  private ObservableCollection<Order> _orders;
  public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders
  {
    get { return _orders; }
    set
    {
      _orders = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Orders");
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName = null)
  {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Binding the grid in the XAML code shouldn't be hard and only requires me to point to the property *Orders*. However, I don't see exactly how the property will be populated from the DB (I haven't seen any *Load* method) nor how the DB will be updated (if the grid value is changed and the binding set to *TwoWay*).

I've googled it but didn't find anything spot-on. Suggestions?

*Data* is autogenerated in the following class.

```
public partial class Data : DbContext
{
  public Data() : base("name=Data") { }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
  }

  public virtual IObservable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when I create an instance of *Data*, the property *Orders* seem to be *null* and I'm not sure how to populate it. There's no methods for loading, enumerating, selecting, where'ing etc... It's of type *IObservable*, not *IEumerable* and I can't see any *ToList* or *ToEnumerable* methods neither...

Edit

As I try to load in different tables into the set, I notice that one of them is *null* for no apparent reason.

[image]

Comment: From your `Data` class, do you have access to the `DbSet` you have declared in your context?

Comment: @octavioccl If I understand you correctly, then yes. The *Data* class **is** my database context and the field *Orders* is a database set. Please see the edition.

Comment: Why are you using `IObservable<T>` type instead `DbSet<T>` in the declaration of your `Order` property. You should use `DbSet<T>`.

Comment: @octavioccl It's automatically generated for me by the TT script that way. I haven't question it, because of that.

Comment: Well, you could change that type in your T4 script or you could use the first solution that I propose using the `Set<T>` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Data` class, you could create a default constructor to set the `Orders` property in your ViewModel as I show as follow:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private Data _data = new Data();

  private ObservableCollection<Order> _orders;
  public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders
  {
    get { return _orders; }
    set
    {
      _orders = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Orders");
    }
  }

  //define a constructor
  public ViewModel()
  {
    _data.Set<Order>().Load();
    this.Orders=_data.Set<Order>().Local;
  }
 //...
}
```

`Local` is a property of the `DbSet<T>` class and It gets an `ObservableCollection<T>` that represents a local view of all `Added`, `Unchanged`, and `Modified` entities in this set. This local view will stay in sync as entities are added or removed from the context. Likewise, entities added to or removed from the local view will automatically be added to or removed from the context.

Now, due to `DbSet<TEntity>.Local` gives you objects that are currently tracked by the `DbContext`,  you need to load first-into memory- the entities you need to bound. That's way you need to call the `Load` method first, to materialize your query.

Finally, WPF natively supports binding to an `ObservableCollection` so *there is no additional code required to have two way data binding with full support for WPF sorting, filtering etc*.

### Update 1

If you change the type of your `Orders` property to `DbSet<Order>` in the `Data` class, then you can set the `Orders` property of your ViewModel this way:

```
    _data.Orders.Load();
    this.Orders=_data.Orders.Local;
```

Comment: This was actually a very interesting reply. I tested to load order before but it didn't work (got null there). Now that you pointed it out, I tried again and took a look at the different tables. It seems that *Orders* is faulty somehow (see the second edit in my question), while the others load in as supposed to. What can be the cause of it? (+1 for clear/extensive reply and a possible bounty if we get it through all the way)

Answer (score -1):

1. Lets clarify that you are using DataGrid (not just Grid). If you add your XAML code it will be useful
2. I don't know any method on DataGrid and usually you can populate collection in constructor or inside property

   public ObservableCollection Orders
   {
       get {
           if(_orders == null) { // populate orders here}
           return _orders; }
       set
       {
           _orders = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Orders"); 
       }
   }
3. To save changes you can take a look on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1157617/5100673)